# Why my Spring OAuth2 Server not working using SSL self-sign ssl?

Tags: java, spring, ssl, oauth, spring-boot

I'm using OAuth 2.0 on my applications. I have 2 apps developed using Spring Boot, one the authentication with url https://192.168.1.30:2999/autenticador and the second, the client, https://192.168.1.30:2901/.

When I'm using the **server without SSL** (http://192.168.1.30:2999/autenticador and https://192.168.1.30:2901/) the authorization **has success**. But, **when I'm using self-sign certificate** I have problems, returning **error 401, Unauthorized**, Authentication Failed: Could not obtain access token. I don't know how and why it's happening.

Observation: The certificate is registred on my computer like trusted then I'm seeing the address bar green.

The client:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The OAuth 2.0 configuration on server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuthConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
         endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
        .withClient("client")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
        .scopes("read", "trust")
        .resourceIds("RESOURCE_ID")
        .secret("secret");
    }
}
```

Here is the Log of client after login success on server:

```
  2016-06-06 16:47:27.376  DEBUG  [nio-2901-exec-4]  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy          / at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
  2016-06-06 16:47:27.377  DEBUG  [nio-2901-exec-4]  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy          / at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
  2016-06-06 16:47:27.378  DEBUG  [nio-2901-exec-4]  w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository   No HttpSession currently exists
  2016-06-06 16:47:27.378  DEBUG  [nio-2901-exec-4]  w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository   No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
  2016-06-06 16:47:27.381  DEBUG  [nio-2901-exec-4]  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy          / at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
  2016-06-06 16:47:27.382  DEBUG  [nio-2901-exec-4]  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy          / at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
  2016-06-06 16:47:27.383  DEBUG  [nio-2901-exec-4]  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy          / at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
  2016-06-06 16:47:27.383  DEBUG  [nio-2901-exec-4]  o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher    Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'POST /logout
  2016-06-06 16:47:27.383  DEBUG  [nio-2901-exec-4]  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy          / at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter'
  2016-06-06 16:47:27.384  DEBUG  [nio-2901-exec-4]  o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher    Checking match of request : '/'; against '/login'
  2016-06-06 16:47:27.384  DEBUG  [nio-2901-exec-4]  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy          / at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
  2016-06-06 16:47:27.384  DEBUG  [nio-2901-exec-4]  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy          / at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
  2016-06-06 16:47:27.386  DEBUG  [nio-2901-exec-4]  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy          / at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
  2016-06-06 16:47:27.389  DEBUG  [nio-2901-exec-4]  o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter    Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.1.30; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
  2016-06-06 16:47:27.389  DEBUG  [nio-2901-exec-4]  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy          / at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
  2016-06-06 16:47:27.389  DEBUG  [nio-2901-exec-4]  o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter    Requested session ID CBA2CC9F09D613F91D95FD4764E48A50 is invalid.
  2016-06-06 16:47:27.389  DEBUG  [nio-2901-exec-4]  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy          / at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
  2016-06-06 16:47:27.389  DEBUG  [nio-2901-exec-4]  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy          / at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
  2016-06-06 16:47:27.390  DEBUG  [nio-2901-exec-4]  o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor      Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /; Attributes: [authenticated]
  2016-06-06 16:47:27.390  DEBUG  [nio-2901-exec-4]  o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor      Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.1.30; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
  2016-06-06 16:47:27.399  DEBUG  [nio-2901-exec-4]  o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased         Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@3fcae110, returned: -1
  2016-06-06 16:47:27.404  DEBUG  [nio-2901-exec-4]  o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter       Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

Comment: Does the certificate available in client jvm trust store?. If not, then you have to create a truststore and add that certificate to trust store and provide that trust store while starting the client jvm

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried this, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the configuration in `"spring-security.xml"` and see if `'requires-channel'` attribute `set to https and not http`? **If not, set all to https and try.**

More info about this issue is here.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-tomcat-https-session

Sample:

```
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" requires-channel="https"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" requires-channel="https"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" requires-channel="https"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="https"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/index" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="https"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/upload/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="https"/>
```

Comment: I do this before too, but didn't work. See my log and you will verify that is not the problem. Thanks for try.

Answer (score 0):

@[Ignacio Ocampo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/770615/ignacio-ocampo) found the problem.

### Problem:

Since I'm using the WSO2 Identity Server in development mode, with an self-signed certificate, Java don't trust on it. And, in some HTTP request to WSO2 endpoints, connection fails by this invalid certificate.

### Temporary solution:

Turn off SSL checking in your development mode.

### Solution:

In a production environment, make sure that you WSO2 Identity Server has a valid certificate.

### Resource Location:

1. [Troubleshooting 401 Unauthorized with x509 (OpenSSL or Self Signed
   Certificate)](https://chanmingman.wordpress.com/2015/06/27/401-unauthorized-when-using-self-signed-certificate-in-sharepoint-2013/)
2. [OpenID Connect with the WSO2 Identity Server 4.5.0 & the WSO2
   OAuth2 Playground](http://sureshatt.blogspot.com.es/2013/08/openid-connect-with-wso2-identity.html)
3. [401 Unauthorized when using Self-Signed certificate in SharePoint
   2013](https://chanmingman.wordpress.com/2015/06/27/401-unauthorized-when-using-self-signed-certificate-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: I know the problem is about self-sign, but I need to open a exception to this SSL to use on intranet.


I can't turn off SSL, like I said it works without this, using only HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having self-sign cert, create a local root CA and then generate the SSL cert from that. Ensure JVM truststore have a copy of the root CA' public key

Comment: I try it too on JVM x86 and x64, but it not working. Maybe I need change some configuration on Spring OAuth2 to accept the certificate.